# Android see log in layout manager

Tags: android, logging, layout-manager

I extended a View and would like to see debugging outputs in the layout manager (without testing on emulator / device). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse? The "Problems" and "Error Log" tabs will hold info if your layout is bugged.

Best regards.

Comment: I mean simple log output (Log.d)

Comment: What do you mean by "layout manager"? If I understand you better now, you want to run your app and see Log info in eclipse, without actually running the app on an emulator or a device? Impossible.

Comment: The layout manager runs the code of the views which are in the layout in order to display them. So it's running also the lines of my code with Log.d. Would like to see it because I need to check some calculations I'm doing in my custom view, using only layout information from xml. Running on the emulator is bit more work and have to make the activity I'm testing MAIN, or tap until I'm there and that's not optimal.